# Linking a shared library in executable vs. another shared lib

Tags: c++, linux, linker, g++, clang++

**tl;dr**

Are there any differences in the way linux loads and links a shared library if the library is linked by an executable or by another shared library?

**Background**

Suppose I have a shared library (e.g. `libA.so`) containing a class with a static `std::map` and a set of singleton classes. Each singleton class has access to the map and statically adds an instance of itself to the map.

There are two scenarios:

1. I use the shared library (`libA.so`) in an executable to read all the registered classes from the global map.
2. I use the shared library (`libA.so`) in another shared library (`libB.so`) and use this new one in an executable. In this case `libB.so` uses the map from `libA.so` to provide some functionality to the executable (like a facade).

**Problem**

If I use (i.e. link) this shared library in an executable (scenario 1), the aforementioned map contains the list of singleton classes, *however*, if I  use this library in another shared library and then use the new one in an executable (scenario 2), the map seems to be empty.

I cannot seem to understand how the linker handles the shared libraries in either of cases.

**Update**

As it turned out `libB.so` does not link to `libA.so` correctly even as explicitly instructed using `-lA` flag of `g++`. Even though I cannot see `libA.so` linked by `libB.so` using `ldd`, `pmap` or `objdump`, I get no runtime errors when using classes of `libA.so`. If I run the same command with `clang++` I can see that *all* required libraries are listed.

Comment: On UNIX systems, shared libraries share memory only for their code pages. The data pages still reside with the process using the library, unless you write special code to make the library use shared memory. I believe Windows has a mode where DLLs will share data as well as code.

Comment: @jxh I'm on Linux, but still cannot understand what happens to all those static initializations when I link the shared library through another shared library and why it works just fine if link it directly by an executable?

Comment: When you produce your second library, are you 100 % sure you make a static linking of the first shared lib?

Comment: @jxh I updated the question and hopefully its more clear now.

Comment: @eugeniu-rosca I am 100% sure that I don't link it statically, since I the library is supposed to be used by other modules.

Comment: @jxh The new executable is a [Node.js addon](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) and is run through the `nodejs` CLI. In the dynamic section of `objdump -p` I can see the following libs marked as `NEEDED`:   `libstdc++.so.6`, `libm.so.6`, `libgcc_s.so.1`, `libc.so.6`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will describe a scenario that could produce the behavior you are seeing.

1. Global constructors of the singleton objects are called, and they get registered against the map.
2. Global constructor of the map is called, causing the map to be initialized into an empty data structure.

Another scenario:

- If you are reading the map from `libB.so` from a global constructor, it may be called before any object has had a chance to register itself.

Generally, there is no guaranteed order of execution of global constructors from different translation units, and certainly not from different shared libraries.

A solution to the first issue above would be to use a singleton style pattern for your map, so that it is initialized on use rather than through a global constructor.

```
TheMap & GlobalMap () {
    static TheMap instance;
    return instance;
}
```

A solution to the second issue above would be suppress accessing the global map from global constructors. That is, change all global constructors in `libB.so` to be initialize on use rather than initialize in a global constructor.

Comment: I think the concept of global constructors is exactly what I was missing. I updated the question just to clarify what I exactly do. I would say that your answer explains just the situation I'm stuck in.

Comment: I think the global constructor for the map executing late in scenario 2 is what is causing your issue, and as I said, there is no guaranteed order of execution of global constructors. You could probably add some print statements to prove that registrations are occurring before the map gets constructed. As to why the order changes when linked by another library, this probably has to do with some object dependency tree that the linker built, but I do not have a definitive answer.

Comment: I just checked with `LD_DEBUG=libs` and found out that in case of the executable I have this line `calling init: /PATH/TO/LIB/libA.so`, which is missing if I try the debug in the second scenario. So You are totally right!

Answer (score 4):

Drepper's paper [How To Write a Shared Library](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) is a good reference on the subject and should answer your question.

You should be sure that in the second scenario, the library is linked only once (e.g. using the exact same path). See [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html) and use e.g. `LD_DEBUG`  etc...

You might also `strace`  your execution to understand what is going on.

And you should check (with `pmap`  or using `cat /proc/$ThePid/maps`)  that the library is loaded only once.

Comment: Please, edit the unaccessible link. +1 for mentioning `pmap`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch as it turned out, the library doesn't get initialized at all  not even to be seen as require DSO when using `ldd` or `objdump -p`. **However** this only happens when using `g++`. With `clang` all the required libraries are linked correctly.